# How to read mp3 metadata in php

Tags: php, metadata, mp3

My problem is simple, i need to read/write metadada from/into a mp3 file from a php script, but I can't find any reliable sorce of information. I'm over a week searching for answers but no real solution.

To explain my self a little better, I need to upload a mp3 file that has metadata attached, read this data and store in my database. After thar initial load, any new mp3 files that will be sent, will not have any metadata, and my system must insert some data into it, like track name, author, and a few others.

I can't find the a working solution for this read/write metadata anywhere, just some offline docs and outdated information.

Answer (score 0):

If your path to your mp3 file is for example "/var/lib/my_mixtape.mp3", then give the code below a try:

```
$mp3FileLocation = "/var/lib/my_mixtape.mp3";
$metaData = id3_get_tag($mp3FileLocation);

// Fetch the necessary information from the $meta
```

For further reference, checkout the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.id3-get-tag.php) on the id3 function.

Comment: I'm trying to use this function, but this needs some PECL extension and do not work without.
I'm trying to get some support from my host to try to solve this, but seems the extension needed is some legacy alpha version 0.2 and don't have any kind of support.

Comment: You'll have to ask your provider to enable it indeed, or import it by yourself if you have sufficient permissions to do so.

Comment: 404 on the php documentation